# Decimal To Binary Conversion

Tags: c#

I tried with this code in C# but could not get the desired output and i cudn't find where my mstaking in logic.

```
int rem,n,num=0; 
while(n>0)  
{ 
    rem=n%2;  
    num=(num*10)+rem;  
    n=n/2;  
}  
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

But it doesn't give me the right output please tell me how can i accomplish it.
 Output:
 6 after conversion it sould be 110 but its 11

Comment: You don't mention anything about what the inputs are, as well as what the outputs are, as well as what you the intention of the algorithm is.  You should elaborate on all of those things so that others can help provide you an answer.

Comment: Like I tell my testers: Expected, Actual, Steps to Reproduce. You have only one of them and a developer will always require the three.

Comment: @Redx i mean that i can accept answer in c++ too becase i work with it too.

Comment: @avrik: You have a problem with the logic ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use method [Convert.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325267(v=VS.71).aspx) for that:

```
string binValue = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
```

If you nead a leading zeros you can use [String PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) method:

```
binValue = binValue.PadLeft(10, '0');
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error is that you're adding the digits to "num" in reverse order.

Answer (score 3):

There's an answer here:  [Decimal to binary conversion in c #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954962/decimal-to-binary-conversion-in-c)

Essentially:

```
int value = 8;
string binary = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
```

Will this solve your problem or do you need to understand why your code wasn't working?

Answer (score 0):

`n` is never set and will therefore always be zero, meaning your `while(n>0)` loop will never be called.

Comment: n is never set and therefore the program won't compile with 'Use of unassigned variable' error. ;)

Comment: Dmitry - I think you mean warning because it is assigned to the value of 0.

Comment: No, I meant 'error'. (Just tested with VS2010. Program doesn't compile.) Maybe there is some setting to treat it as a warning, but by default it's an error.

Comment: @Ramhound `int rem,n,num=0;` only sets num.  rem and n remain unassigned.  They do not default to 0.  Only fields take default values, not local variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
From Decimal to Binary...


using System;

class Program{

   static void Main(string[] args){

      try{

     int i = (int)Convert.ToInt64(args[0]);
         Console.WriteLine("\n{0} converted to Binary is {1}\n",i,ToBinary(i));

      }catch(Exception e){

         Console.WriteLine("\n{0}\n",e.Message);

      }

   }//end Main


        public static string ToBinary(Int64 Decimal)
        {
            // Declare a few variables we're going to need
            Int64 BinaryHolder;
            char[] BinaryArray;
            string BinaryResult = "";

            while (Decimal > 0)
            {
                BinaryHolder = Decimal % 2;
                BinaryResult += BinaryHolder;
                Decimal = Decimal / 2;
            }

            // The algoritm gives us the binary number in reverse order (mirrored)
            // We store it in an array so that we can reverse it back to normal
            BinaryArray = BinaryResult.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(BinaryArray);
            BinaryResult = new string(BinaryArray);

            return BinaryResult;
        }


}//end class Program



From Binary to Decimal...


using System;

class Program{

   static void Main(string[] args){

      try{

         int i = ToDecimal(args[0]);
         Console.WriteLine("\n{0} converted to Decimal is {1}",args[0],i);

      }catch(Exception e){

         Console.WriteLine("\n{0}\n",e.Message);

      }

   }//end Main


                public static int ToDecimal(string bin)
        {
                    long l = Convert.ToInt64(bin,2);
                    int i = (int)l;
                    return i;
        }


}//end class Program
```

Code snippet taken from [this](http://kyrathaba.dcmembers.com/errata/binary_decimal.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
string binary = "";
while (decimalNum != 0) {
    int nextDigit = decimalNum & 0x01;
    binary = nextDigit + binary;
    decimalNum = decimalNum >> 1;
}

Console.WriteLine(binary);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 100;
for (int i = sizeof(n) * 8 - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    n & (1 << i) ? printf("1") : printf("0");
}
```

And the result is:

```
00000000000000000000000001100100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = value;
int rem = 0;
int round = 0;
int result = 0; 

while(number > 1)  
{ 
    rem = number % 2;  
    result = result + (rem * (round ^ 10));  
    number = number / 2;  

    round ++;
}    

result = result + (number * (round ^ 10));  



Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: its giving error that "Use of unassigned local Variable Round".

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
                prime_not();
            else
                binary();
        }



        private void binary()
        {
            label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text), 2);
        }

        private void prime_not()
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text) % 2 == 0)
                label1.Text= "Not Prime";
            else
                label1.Text = "Prime";
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert Decimal to Binary

```
int len = 8;

public string DeicmalToBin(int value, int len) 
{
        try
        {
            return (len > 1 ? DeicmalToBin(value >> 1, len - 1) : null) + "01"[value & 1];
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

[For more details Decimal to binary conversion](http://kodecenter.com/article?id=f3ed25f1-2563-4323-9f43-c4fbbc9c372f)

Answer (score 0):

```
 int num = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
 int rem = 0;
 string res = "";

 do
 {
     rem = num % 2;
     num /= 2;
     res=rem.ToString()+res;               
 } while (num > 0);

 textBox1.Text=res;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22686847)