# How to convert from decimal to binary .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm a bit confused on decimal to binary number conversion. Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub tbxDecimal_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbxDecimal.TextChanged

        If rdbDecmial.Checked = True And IsNumeric(tbxDecimal.Text) Then
            Dim bin, dec As Double
            Dim output As String
            dec = Convert.ToDouble(tbxDecimal.Text)
            For i = 1 To dec Step (???)
                dec = i Mod 2
                If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    bin = 0
                Else
                    bin = 1
                End If
                output &= Convert.ToString(bin)
            Next
            tbxBinary.Text = output
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I typed in a decimal number in one box, the incorrect numbers come out. I know I have to have some kind of stepping size for this loop, however what should I put in?

Comment: I know this question posted long time ago, but.... will any of provided answers convert **decimal** to binary? I don't think so. Or question is titled wrong, or all provided answers are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `While`, not a `For`; you should loop as long as `dec` is not 0. Also, you should treat the number as `Integer` rather than `Double`; this algorithm only works for integers. Another issue is that you're concatenating the bits in the wrong order.

```
Private Function ToBinary(dec As Integer) As String
    Dim bin As Integer
    Dim output As String
    While dec <> 0
        If dec Mod 2 = 0 Then
            bin = 0
        Else
            bin = 1
        End If
        dec = dec \ 2
        output = Convert.ToString(bin) & output
    End While
    If output Is Nothing Then
        Return "0"
    Else
        Return output
    End If
End Function
```

BTW, I assume you're doing that manually for learning purposes, but if you're not, you can just use the `Convert.ToString` method:

```
output = Convert.ToString(dec, 2)
```

Comment: Actually it gives me `"1"` as output where I should expect `"000001"`

Comment: @Marine1 why do you expect that? you need to pad it with the number of 0 you want. How could it now if you want it on 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: `output.PadLeft(LengthOfStringYouNeed, "0"c)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in conversion to a binary string representation which you could use, and you can also use TryParse to make sure the text can be converted to a number (IsNumeric can be a bit more permissive than you might want):

```
Private Sub tbxDecimal_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbxDecimal.TextChanged
    If rdbDecmial.Checked Then
        Dim num As Int64
        If Int64.TryParse(tbxDecimal.Text, num) Then
            tbxBinary.Text = Convert.ToString(num, 2)
        Else
            tbxBinary.Text = ""
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that your way calculate the correct binary? I tried it with 1399775318 and don't get the expected 1010100100100010010000010101010

Comment: @PeterCo You should expect 1010011011011101110000001010110.

Comment: So you say the other two examples calculates both wrong?

Comment: @PeterCo It is *unlikely* that a Framework method would be wrong. Are you using Option Strict On so that all your variable types match up?

Comment: @PeterCo When Kaz-LA's method is modified to work with Option Strict On, it too gives 1010011011011101110000001010110.

Comment: You are right. With "Option Strict on" I see the probem too. Thank you for that hint!

Answer (score 0):

Heres the VB.NET version for you

```
Dim decimalNumber As Integer = Integer.Parse(tbxDecimal.Text)

Dim remainder As Integer
Dim result As String = String.Empty
While decimalNumber > 0
    remainder = decimalNumber Mod 2
    decimalNumber /= 2
    result = remainder.ToString() & result
End While
Console.WriteLine("Binary:  {0}", result)
```

Source: [Decimal to binary conversion in c #](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8862608/1080742)

Answer (score 0):

C#:

```
static string DecimalToBinary(int num) 
{
    var bin = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    do
    {
      bin.Insert(0, (num%2));
      num/=2;
    }while (num != 0);

    return bin.ToString();
}
```

VB:

```
Private Shared Function DecimalToBinary(num As Integer) As String
   Dim bin = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
      Do
         bin.Insert(0, (num Mod 2))
         num /= 2
      Loop While num <> 0

   Return bin.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Your VB version does not work correctly due to the line `num /= 2` because the invisible R.H.S. is a double and the implicit conversion to an integer uses rounding, not truncation. E.g. with 1399775318 your method gives 1010100100100010010000010101010 but the correct answer is 1010011011011101110000001010110. To correct it, use `num = num \ 2` (or `num \= 2`).

Answer (score 0):

Take this code to your btnCalc and paste it

```
Dim iptbxNumberDec as integer

Dim iptbxNumber as string

Dim intBin as integer

iptbxNumber = inputbox("Please enter the number that you want to convect to binary from decimal","Number ")

integer.tryparse(iptbxNumber,iptbxNumberDec)

if iptbxNumberDec > 0 then 

iptbxNumberDec / = 10

Do while iptbxNumberDec <> 0

if iptbxNumberDec mod 2 = 0 then

intBin = 0 

lblOutput.text = vbcrlf & vbcrlf & intBin & " " 

else

intBin = 1 

lblOutput.text = vbcrlf & vbcrlf & intBin & " " 

iptbxNumber / = 10

Do while iptbxNumberDec <> 0

if iptbxNumberDec mod 2 = 0 then

intBin = 0

lblOutput.text = vbcrlf & vbcrlf & intBin & " " 

else

intBin =  1

lblOutput.text = vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
intBin & " "

intBin += 1 

endif



loop

endif
```

use this code in visual basic

Answer (score 0):

So my solution with ULong and Option Strict On.

For example: num = 4036854942 and the result is: 11110000100111011000010010011110

Compare it with: http://unicode-table.com/en/1D11E/

```
Private Shared Function DecimalToBinary(num As ULong) As String

    Dim bin = New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    Dim modnum As Decimal

    Do
        modnum = num Mod 2
        bin.Insert(0, (modnum))
        num = CType((num - modnum) / 2, ULong)

    Loop While num <> 0

    Return bin.ToString()

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str_bianry as String
Dim index_number as integer =65

while index_number > 0
str &= index_number MOD 2
index_number \=2
end loop

Dim char_binary as char=str.toArray()
Array.Reverse(char_binary)
msgbox(String.join("",char_binary).padLeft(8,"0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

VB:

```
Function DecimalToBinary(num As Integer) As String

    Dim Binary_String As String

    Binary_String = ""

    Do While num > 0
        Binary_String = num Mod 2 & Binary_String
        num = num \ 2
    Loop

    Return Binary_String

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution in VB.Net:

```
Sub Main(args As String())

    Dim number As Integer = 14
    Dim binary As String

    While number > 0
        Dim temp As String = number Mod 2
        number = Floor(number / 2)  

        binary += temp
    End While

    Console.WriteLine(binary.Reverse.ToArray)

End Sub
```