# Decimal to Binary Conversion Error

Tags: binary, decimal, void

How do you fix the following problem converting from decimal to binary?

```
void tobinary(int bin) {
    string binary = Convert.ToInt32(bin, 2);
}
```

These are the errors:

> **Error 2:** Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.IFormatProvider' 42
>
> **Error 1:** The best overloaded method match for 'System.Convert.ToInt32(object, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments  42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see:
[Decimal to binary conversion in c #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954962/decimal-to-binary-conversion-in-c)

it should be:

```
void tobinary(int bin) {
string binary = Convert.ToString(bin, 2);}
```