# Working with variables Strings in C# using function ".insert(int startIndex, string value)"

Tags: c#, string, xamarin, insert, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to write an app to convert different number systems. In the code below I check if the rest is "0" or "1".  If it is the program should add "0" or "1" to my result string `binaer`.  It don't work and I have really no idea why.

```
public void dezinbin(int dez) {
    var binaer = "";        // erstellt den leeren Ausgabestrang
    var platzhalter = dez;                  //Platzhalter für dez, da des nicht verändert werden kann

    for (var i = 0; i<16; i++){
        var binarrest = platzhalter % 2;  //teilt dez durch 2 und speichert den rest in binaerrest
        platzhalter = platzhalter / 2;          //verringert die dez-Eingabe um die hälfte
        if (binarrest == 0) //hängt den binaerrest jeweils an den Anfang des Ausgabestrings
        {
            binaer.Insert(0, "0");
        }
        else 
        {
            binaer.Insert(0, "1");
        }
                    }
    this.bin = binaer;   //gibt den Ausgabestring zurück
}
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".  Does it crash?  Do you get an error?  Does it run but give the wrong result?

Comment: further, C# has built in functions to handle this conversion:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954962/decimal-to-binary-conversion-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this syntax:

binaer = binaer.Insert(0, "0");

because insert has not changed the "binaer" itself.

Comment: perfect, that was the mistake.
Thank u very much

Answer (score 1):

Am I right to understand you want to append "0" or "1" to the string binaer?

if you want to append to the end try

```
    binaer +=  "1"
```

if you want to put it in front , then try

```
    binaer = "1" + binaer;
```

Answer (score 0):

try using 
                    binaer += "0";
instead of 
                    binaer.Insert(0, "0");

and so on and so forth.