# C# - ushort array to multiple bits

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, data-conversion, ushort

I have a `ushort[3]` data read from device. Now I want to convert it to the following format:

### [image: Picture Here]

The first word `ushort[0] --> 16 bits`

The second word `ushort[1] --> 8 bits & 2 * 4-bits`

The Third word `ushort[2] --> 4 * 4bits`

---

For example:

The ushort[3] is `3 256 16`

### After converting:

The first word `0000 0000 0000 0011`

The second word `ushort[1] --> 0 1 0000 0000`

The Third word `ushort[2] --> 0 0 1 0`

---

At last store it as byte[30] in c#

I hope I have clearly explain this problem, and welcome any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: You example, does not fit your definition. ushort[1] is only 10 Bits (not 8 & 2 * 4 = 16) and ushort[2] is only 4 Bits (instead of 4 * 4 = 16)

Comment: If you are trying to convert `ushort`s to binary form, you can find solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954962/decimal-to-binary-conversion-in-c

Comment: @RomanoZumbé  sorry for my expression. The yellow zone in the picture are 4-bits data which is not standard data type of C#, you can consider it as a byte whose high 4 bits default values are 0.