# Custom number to binary?

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and im trying to get a custom number to convert to binary. I've looked up several forms here on stack overflow and they have similar code to this, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
Console.WriteLine("You have chosen binary, input a number then it will be converted to binary.");
string num1input = Console.ReadLine();
double num1 = double.Parse(num1input);
var binary = Convert.ToString(num1, 2);
Console.WriteLine("{0} converted to binary is {1} " ,num1, binary);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to binary"? Do you mean a `string` representation containing the base-2 representation of an `Int32` value - or something else?

Comment: What's a custom number? It looks like you're expecting the number to be entered as a floating point value. Do you want to generate the binary equivalent of a floating point number?

Comment: I  note that your example uses `System.Double` which is an IEEE-754 floating-point type, which has a non-trivial binary representation.

Comment: What do you mean by `but it doesn't work`?

Comment: None of this code has anything to do with conversion to binary. I think you misunderstand what a `double` type is. As Dai said, it's a floating point number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert integer to binary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954962/convert-integer-to-binary-in-c-sharp)

Comment: There isn't an overload of `Convert.ToString` that takes a double and a base. The compiler will be complaining that it can't convert from int to IFormatProvider..

Comment: you are trying to use Convert.ToString Method (Int32, Int32) with double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question if you are trying to convert an integer or a floating point value to a binary string representation.

For an integer, use this code:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen binary, input a number then it will be converted to binary.");
    string num1input = Console.ReadLine();
    int num1 = int.Parse(num1input);

    var binary = Convert.ToString(num1, 2);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} converted to binary is {1} ", num1, binary);
}
```

For a double, this code might be what you want:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen binary, input a number then it will be converted to binary.");
    string num1input = Console.ReadLine();
    double num1 = double.Parse(num1input);

    long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(num1);

    var binary = Convert.ToString(bits, 2);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} converted to binary is {1} ", num1, binary);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this exercise interesting, so here is what I did :

```
public IEnumerable<char> ConvertToBase2(int myNumber) {
    while(myNumber != 0) {
        var returnValue = (myNumber%2 == 0) ? '0' : '1';

        myNumber = (myNumber % 2 == 0) ? myNumber / 2 : 
            (myNumber - 1) / 2;

        yield return returnValue;
    }
}
Console.Write(String.Concat(
    ConvertToBase2(9).Reverse()
));
```

It works only for integers. I don't remember exactly how floating points numbers are implemented.

By the way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50472299/1251861) is a better answer ;-)