# textBox1.Text (hex) to texBox2.Text(binary)

Tags: c#, binary, hex

how do I convert text in textBox1 from Hex to Binary and display it in textBox2

I don't even know where to start

Comment: Start by watching/reading an introduction to C#, WinForms/WPF and then try to solve your problem, when you encounter specific problems/questions, you can ask on StackOverflow

Comment: Try Google always first before coming here!

Comment: Dupe of [Convert integer to hexadecimal and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139957/215552) and [Convert integer to binary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2954962/215552). Try breaking your problems into individual steps and searching for answers to those individual steps.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an hex string to a binary string you should do :

```
string binaryValue = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexValue, 16), 2);
```

Then for the TextBox there is ton of tutorial to make it.